# How to solve AWS CloudFront SSL Certificate Doesn't Exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-iam

When I was adding the `IamCertificateId` property to my `AWS::CloudFront::Distribution` in CloudFormation, I got the following error:

> Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't in us-east-1 region, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain."

I did make sure that the certificate exists, by running the `aws iam list-server-certificates` [command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-server-certificates.html) and making sure the value of the `IamCertificateId` property matches [the `ASCA` prefixed IAM ID](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html) of the certificate.

I am disregarding the `us-east-1` region message since IAM is a global service and I'm not using an ACM certificate. Also, I'm operating in the China `cn-north-1` region, in case that makes a difference.

I'm pretty sure the certificate is "valid", because I'm assuming AWS wouldn't have allowed me to [upload the certificate with `aws iam upload-server-certificate`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/upload-server-certificate.html) if it were malformed.

The error message, therefore, isn't pointing me to the solution. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your certificate may be valid, but perhaps not valid for *CloudFront*. What the error message didn't point out, is something you can find tucked away in [the docs for uploading a certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/upload-server-certificate.html):

> **Note:**
> If you are uploading a server certificate specifically for use with Amazon CloudFront distributions, you must specify a path using the path parameter. The path must begin with /cloudfront and must include a trailing slash (for example, /cloudfront/test/ ).

Therefore, make sure that you add `--path "/cloudfront/"` in your `aws iam upload-server-certificate` command.

Comment: I've added the path `"/cloudfront/"`, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Yann Stoneman, how did you generate the private key, certificate body, and certificate chain for the cloudfront distribution?

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/route-53-lets-encrypt-wildcard-certificate-with-acme-sh/) to generate the three files.

Comment: @Brian -- in my case, someone else on my team gave me a PFX-encoded signed certificate file and then I followed this post on AWS to convert them into an AWS-acceptable format: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-import-pfx-formatted-certificates-into-aws-certificate-manager-using-openssl/

Comment: According to this [document](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html#https-requirements-size-of-public-key), the length of the CloudFront certificate must not be longer than 2048 bits. My certificate was 4096 bits, that's the reason for the problem in my case.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this same issue when trying to attach an AWS Certificate to a CloudFront distribution.

The issue had to do with the fact that the AWS Certificate was provisioned in the **eu-west-1** region.

AWS made it clear:

> To use a certificate in AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) to require HTTPS between viewers and CloudFront, make sure you request (or import) the certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) Region (**us-east-1**).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-requirements.html

**Here's I fixed it**:

All I had to do is to provision another AWS certificate in the US East (N. Virginia) Region (**us-east-1**) and then referenced it in the CloudFront distribution in the **eu-west-1** region.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error. I was using Terraform to provision a Cloudfront distribution in a region that is not us-east-1. I was positive it was a variable error. Somewhere I must have had a variable pointing to the wrong region us-east-1.

But indeed, like user Promise Preston pointed out, the certificate must be in us-east-1, even if the Cloudfront distribution I am creating is not going to be in us-east-1.

Solution: I provided my Terraform code with the ARN of a valid certificate from us-east-1, even if the distribution I was creating was not going to be in us-east-1. And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it was because my build system had accidentally switched a slash `/` on Windows (but it was working on Linux). My CloudFormation file had:

```
        "CloudfrontDistribution": {
            "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution",
            "DependsOn": "CloudfrontS3LogsBucket",
            "Condition": "DRDeactivated",
            "Properties": {
                "DistributionConfig": {
<--- snip snip -->
                    "ViewerCertificate": {
                        "AcmCertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:0123456789:certificate\\XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
                        "SslSupportMethod": "sni-only",
                        "MinimumProtocolVersion": "TLSv1.2_2019"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

The `AcmCertificateArn` was wrong in the Cloud Formation code above. Instead of

```
"AcmCertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:0123456789:certificate\\XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
```

it should have been:

```
"AcmCertificateArn": "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:0123456789:certificate/XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX",
```